# Extracting slots from list of lists in python

Tags: python, list, sorting, iteration

I have list of lists in following format which I need to pass to an api.

```
[
    [0, 4, 0, 4, 59], [0, 5, 0, 5, 59], [0, 6, 0, 6, 59], [0, 13, 0, 13, 59],
    [0, 14, 0, 14, 59], [0, 21, 0, 21, 59], [0, 22, 0, 22, 59], 
    [1, 5, 0, 5, 59], [1, 6, 0, 6, 59], [1, 13, 0, 13, 59], [1, 14, 0, 14, 59],
    [1, 21, 0, 21, 59], [1, 22, 0, 22, 59], [2, 5, 0, 5, 59], [2, 6, 0, 6, 59], 
    [2, 13, 0, 13, 59], [2, 14, 0, 14, 59], [2, 21, 0, 21, 59], 
    [2, 22, 0, 22, 59], [3, 5, 0, 5, 59], [3, 6, 0, 6, 59], [3, 13, 0, 13, 59],
    [3, 14, 0, 14, 59], [3, 21, 0, 21, 59], [3, 22, 0, 22, 59], 
    [4, 5, 0, 5, 59], [4, 6, 0, 6, 59], [4, 13, 0, 13, 59], [4, 14, 0, 14, 59],
    [4, 21, 0, 21, 59], [4, 22, 0, 22, 59], [5, 5, 0, 5, 59], [5, 6, 0, 6, 59],
    [5, 13, 0, 13, 59], [5, 14, 0, 14, 59], [5, 21, 0, 21, 59], 
    [5, 22, 0, 22, 59], [6, 5, 0, 5, 59], [6, 6, 0, 6, 59], [6, 13, 0, 13, 59],
    [6, 14, 0, 14, 59], [6, 21, 0, 21, 59], [6, 22, 0, 22, 59] 
]
```

In each list first element represents the day, and following elements represents from hour & mins to hour & mins. From the example above, for day 0,  **slot1** is 04:00 to 6:59, **slot 2 is** 13:00 to 14:59, and **slot3 is** 21:00 to 22:59.

I am trying to simplify the lists to as follows.

```
[0, 04:00, 6:59, 13:00, 14:59, 21:00, 22:59]....
```

Essentially Extracting and combining the hours slots for each day into a single list, hence final output would have only 7 lists from day 0-6.

Also notice above format could change, for any given day there might only be 1 slot or might not have a slot, so the slots could vary between 0-3 for each day.

So far I manage to join the hours and mins as follows 
`

```
 start = float(str(from_hr) + str('.')+ str(from_min))
 end =   float(str(to_hr) + str('.')+ str(to_min))`
```

Comment: To me it looks like your input is a list of minutes of an hour that are in use, and your concept of slots is to join consecutive minutes into a single unit. So you should test your conversion function with varying numbers of consecutive hours. Not sure what your current float and str code is trying to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do something like this:

```
input = [[0, 4, 0, 5, 59],[0, 5, 0, 5, 59], [0, 6, 0, 6, 59], [0, 13, 0, 13, 59], [0, 14, 0, 14, 59], [0, 21, 0, 21, 59], [0, 22, 0, 22, 59], [1, 5, 0, 5, 59], [1, 6, 0, 6, 59], [1, 13, 0, 13, 59], [1, 14, 0, 14, 59], [1, 21, 0, 21, 59], [1, 22, 0, 22, 59], [2, 5, 0, 5, 59], [2, 6, 0, 6, 59], [2, 13, 0, 13, 59], [2, 14, 0, 14, 59], [2, 21, 0, 21, 59], [2, 22, 0, 22, 59], [3, 5, 0, 5, 59], [3, 6, 0, 6, 59], [3, 13, 0, 13, 59], [3, 14, 0, 14, 59], [3, 21, 0, 21, 59], [3, 22, 0, 22, 59], [4, 5, 0, 5, 59], [4, 6, 0, 6, 59], [4, 13, 0, 13, 59], [4, 14, 0, 14, 59], [4, 21, 0, 21, 59], [4, 22, 0, 22, 59], [5, 5, 0, 5, 59], [5, 6, 0, 6, 59], [5, 13, 0, 13, 59], [5, 14, 0, 14, 59], [5, 21, 0, 21, 59], [5, 22, 0, 22, 59], [6, 5, 0, 5, 59], [6, 6, 0, 6, 59], [6, 13, 0, 13, 59], [6, 14, 0, 14, 59], [6, 21, 0, 21, 59], [6, 22, 0, 22, 59]]

output = {}
for row in input:
    key = row[0]
    output.setdefault(key, [str(key)])
    output[key].append('%d:%02d' % (row[1], row[2]))
    output[key].append('%d:%02d' % (row[3], row[4]))

result = output.values()
```

Comment: this solves 75% of problem, I get each list like ['0', '4:00', '5:59', '5:00', '5:59', '6:00', '6:59', '13:00', '13:59', '14:00', '14:59', '21:00', '21:59', '22:00', '22:59'], but I want to this to be like ['0','4:00,'5:59','13:00','14:59','21:00','22:59']

Comment: Please clarify on what criteria you include or exclude a time slot in the list? From your example it's not clear which time slots need to be included.

Comment: ['1', '5:00', '5:59', '6:00', '6:59', '13:00', '13:59', '14:00', '14:59', '21:00', '21:59', '22:00', '22:59']. In this example I have a gap between 6:59 and 13:00. Hence my first slot would start at 5 an finish at 6:69. Second would start at 13 and finish at 14:59, since there is break between 14:59 and 21:00. Essentially if there is break in sequence.

Answer (score 1):

I also assume that you wish to:
(a) Combine consecutive appointments (i.e. one starting immediately after the previous one ends)
(b) Format these in the manner shown above
(c) Group these by day in flattened lists.

If so, you can solve this problem using the following approach:

(a) Make a helper function that transforms your day, hour and minute variables into minutes:

```
def get_minute_val(day_val,hour_val,min_val):
    return (24*60*day_val)+(60*hour_val)+min_val
```

(b) Make a function that takes two appointments, and either combines them to one if they are consecutive, or returns them uncombined if they are not

```
def combine_if_consec(first,second):
    #Check whether appointments are consecutive
    if( get_minute_val(first[0],first[3],first[4]) + 1 == 
        get_minute_val(second[0],second[1],second[2])):
        #If so, return list containing combined appointment
        return [[first[0],first[1],first[2],second[3],second[4]]]
    else:
        #Else return uncombined appointments
        return [first,second]
```

(c) Iteratively call this on every appointment in the list, comparing vs. the most recently added appointment. I have a slightly hacky method for dealing with the first appointment.

```
def combine_all_appointments(app_list):
    #Add first appointment to app list
    output_list = [test[0]]

    #Loop through remaining appointments
    for next_app in app_list[1:]:
        #Remove most recent appointment to output list
        prev_app = output_list.pop()

        #Add either 2 combined appointments, or one single appointment to outputlist
        output_list += combine_if_overlap(prev_app,next_app)

    return output_list
```

(d) Make a function that does the formatting you want

```
def format_appointments(app_list):
    return [[x[0],'%d:%02d' % (x[1],x[2]),'%d:%02d' %(x[3],x[4])] for x in app_list]
```

(e) and a separate one to group appointments by days, and flatten by day.

```
def group_by_day(app_list):
    output = {}
    #Loop through appointments
    for app in app_list:
        #Create new entry if day not yet in output dict
        if app[0] not in output:
            output[app[0]] = app[1:]
        #Add appointment values to relevant day
        else:
            output[app[0]] += app[1:]
    #Flatten dictionary
    return [[k, *output[k]] for k in output]
```

Testing this on your input:

```
test = [[0, 4, 0, 4, 59],[0, 5, 0, 5, 59], [0, 6, 0, 6, 59], [0, 13, 0, 13, 59], [0, 14, 0, 14, 59], [0, 21, 0, 21, 59], [0, 22, 0, 22, 59], [1, 5, 0, 5, 59], [1, 6, 0, 6, 59], [1, 13, 0, 13, 59], [1, 14, 0, 14, 59], [1, 21, 0, 21, 59], [1, 22, 0, 22, 59], [2, 5, 0, 5, 59], [2, 6, 0, 6, 59], [2, 13, 0, 13, 59], [2, 14, 0, 14, 59], [2, 21, 0, 21, 59], [2, 22, 0, 22, 59], [3, 5, 0, 5, 59], [3, 6, 0, 6, 59], [3, 13, 0, 13, 59], [3, 14, 0, 14, 59], [3, 21, 0, 21, 59], [3, 22, 0, 22, 59], [4, 5, 0, 5, 59], [4, 6, 0, 6, 59], [4, 13, 0, 13, 59], [4, 14, 0, 14, 59], [4, 21, 0, 21, 59], [4, 22, 0, 22, 59], [5, 5, 0, 5, 59], [5, 6, 0, 6, 59], [5, 13, 0, 13, 59], [5, 14, 0, 14, 59], [5, 21, 0, 21, 59], [5, 22, 0, 22, 59], [6, 5, 0, 5, 59], [6, 6, 0, 6, 59], [6, 13, 0, 13, 59], [6, 14, 0, 14, 59], [6, 21, 0, 21, 59], [6, 22, 0, 22, 59]]

app_list = combine_all_appointments(test)
formatted = format_appointments(app_list)
grouped = group_by_day(formatted)
```

returns

```
[[0, '4:00', '6:59', '13:00', '14:59', '21:00', '22:59'], [1, '5:00', '6:59', '13:00', '14:59', '21:00', '22:59'], [2, '5:00', '6:59', '13:00', '14:59', '21:00', '22:59'], [3, '5:00', '6:59', '13:00', '14:59', '21:00', '22:59'], [4, '5:00', '6:59', '13:00', '14:59', '21:00', '22:59'], [5, '5:00', '6:59', '13:00', '14:59', '21:00', '22:59'], [6, '5:00', '6:59', '13:00', '14:59', '21:00', '22:59']]
```

Comment: Yes there is typo in my example, I fixed that. Your second assumption is correct, I want to combine consecutive ones. But my final list for a given day should be like [0, 4.00, 6:59, 13:00, 14:59, 21:00, 22:59]

Comment: Ok, is my answer what you were looking for?

Comment: ['0', '4:00', '4:59', '5:00', '5:59', '6:00', '6:59', '13:00', '13:59', '14:00', '14:59', '21:00', '21:59', '22:00', '22:59'].  I am getting to this point, but some consecutive values are still appearing.

Comment: Ok, I can't see any consecutive appointments in my example above. Which one is an issue?

Comment: Is it possible to separate each day into a list, output would contain only 0-6 7 lists with each day and appointments.